# django model form

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-forms, django-views

I have a very simple model form, but for some reason, the code fails to syncdb and throws an error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CharField'

the code is as follows (in my models.py):

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea, forms
from django.forms.fields import DateField, ChoiceField, MultipleChoiceField

class SubmitJobDTP(models.Model):
    SERVICE_CHOICES = (
        ('blog', (
            ('DTP1', 'cccccccccccccccccc: GBP 65.00'),
            ('DTP2', 'vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv: GBP 110.00'),
            ('DTP3', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb: GBP 175.00'))
        )
    )
    package = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=SERVICE_CHOICES)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    email_address = models.EmailField()    
    attachment_1 = models.FileField(upload_to='uploadir')
    attachment_2 = models.FileField(upload_to='uploadir')
    attachment_3 = models.FileField(upload_to='uploadir')
    attachment_4 = models.FileField(upload_to='uploadir')
    attachment_5 = models.FileField(upload_to='uploadir')
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class SubmitJobForm(ModelForm): 
    attachment_1 = forms.FileField(label='Attach file 1',required=False)
    attachment_2 = forms.FileField(label='Attach file 2',required=False)
    attachment_3 = forms.FileField(label='Attach file 3',required=False)
    attachment_4 = forms.FileField(label='Attach file 4',required=False)
    attachment_5 = forms.FileField(label='Attach file 5',required=False)
    package = forms.CharField(required=False)
    firstname = forms.CharField(required=False)
    lastname = forms.CharField(required=False)
    contact_number = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    email_address = forms.EmailField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = SubmitJobDTP
        fields = ('package', 'first name', 'last name', 'contact_number',
            'email_address', 'comments', 'attachment_1', 'attachment_2',
            'attachment_3', 'attachment_4', 'attachment_5')
```

A dpasted code is on: http://dpaste.com/607823/

I wonder what the problem could be: The FileField in the modelform syncdb's correctly, but the other fields: CharField, IntegerField and EmailField do not seem to work. I have read the django docs on model form and I cannot seem to find anything particularly related to this error.

Any suggestions would be much apperciated.

Comment: I would suggest reading up (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb) on what `syncdb` does - it doesn't touch `ModelForm` classes, it creates tables defined by `django.db.models.Model` subclasses.  Try running `./manage.py shell` or any other management command and you'll see you have an import syntax error in your code, `from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea, forms`

Comment: @James, a word on how you are using forms. A ModelForm is meant to minimise the amount of custom code you have to write. By declaring each field that already exists in the model, you are effectively creating a standard form. Read more on ModelForms, and save yourself time and bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not actually importing the forms module.

```
>>> from django.forms import forms
>>> forms.CharField
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CharField'
>>> from django import forms
>>> forms.CharField
<class 'django.forms.fields.CharField'>
```

So, you want to change your imports to the following:

```
from django import forms
```

Then to reference a ModelForm:

```
class SubmitJobForm(forms.ModelForm):
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Josh! I nearly wasted 4 hours trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

You may using in top of forms.py

**from django.forms import forms**
instead of this use 
**from django import forms**